# System.Windows.Media.Matrix does not use System.Double precision 64-bit number?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use Matrix from System.Windows.Media but I found a limitation that I don't understand.

Case 1 :

```
double m11 = 0.0000001, // 1E-07
    m12 = 0,
    m21 = 0,
    m22 = 0.0000001; // 1E-07

var mat = new Matrix(m11, m12, m21, m22, 0, 0);

var det = mat.Determinant; // det = 9.9999999999999988E-15 <==> m11*m22-m12*m21 = 1E-07 * 1E-07 = 1E-14

if (mat.HasInverse) // true
    mat.Invert(); // OK
```

In this first case we see : all seem to be good !

Case 2 :

```
double m11 = 0.00000001, // 1E-08
    m12 = 0,
    m21 = 0,
    m22 = 0.0000001; // 1E-07

var mat = new Matrix(m11, m12, m21, m22, 0, 0);

var det = mat.Determinant; // det = 9.9999999999999988E-16 <==> m11*m22-m12*m21 = 1E-08 * 1E-07 = 1E-15

if (mat.HasInverse) // false
    mat.Invert(); // KO : System.InvalidOperationException: 'Transform is not invertible.'
```

But in this second case we can see (Although the matrix checks that it is square and that its determinant is different from zero) HasInverse is false and Invert could throw an exception. Here the only difference that I can see is the precision needed during the calculation 1E-15. But Matrix seem to use double and System.Double precision in 64-bit should use :

> values ranging from negative 1.79769313486232e308 to positive
>   1.79769313486232e30

So why ? Thanks for any message which could be help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix class DOES use doubles. [You can check the source code here.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Media/Matrix.cs,13b7d422c46ba7a0)

```
public double Determinant
{
    get
    {
        switch (_type)
        {
        case MatrixTypes.TRANSFORM_IS_IDENTITY:
        case MatrixTypes.TRANSFORM_IS_TRANSLATION:
            return 1.0;
        case MatrixTypes.TRANSFORM_IS_SCALING:
        case MatrixTypes.TRANSFORM_IS_SCALING | MatrixTypes.TRANSFORM_IS_TRANSLATION:
            return(_m11  * _m22);
        default:
            return(_m11  * _m22) - (_m12 * _m21);
        }
    }
}
```

(where _m11 etc are all `double`)

The following code prints "Same results!", indicating that there is no difference between your calculation and `Matrix.Determinant`:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double m11 = 0.00000001, // 1E-08
                m12 = 0,
                m21 = 0,
                m22 = 0.0000001; // 1E-07        

            double det = m11 * m22 - m12 * m21;
            Console.WriteLine(det);

            var mat = new System.Windows.Media.Matrix(m11, m12, m21, m22, 0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(mat.Determinant);

            if (mat.Determinant == det)
                Console.WriteLine("Same results!"); // This is printed.

            Console.WriteLine(mat.HasInverse); // Has no inverse, though.
        }
    }
}
```

The answer as to why it says there is no inverse can be found by looking at the implementation of `HasInverse`:

```
public bool HasInverse
{
    get
    {
        return !DoubleUtil.IsZero(Determinant);
    }
}
```

Where `DoubleUtil.IsZero()` is implemented thusly (I have simplified this to make it more obvious what's happening):

```
public static bool IsZero(double value)
{
    return Math.Abs(value) < 2.22044604925031E-15;
}
```

In this case, `value` is `1E-15` which is less than `2.22044604925031E-15` so `DoubleUtil.IsZero()` returns `true` and hence `Matrix.HasInverse` returns `false`.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer AND your link !

So alternative question, why define this constant for double in this case ?

Comment: @AmauryCOLMANT There's actually a comment in the source code for `DoubleUtil` for that value: `internal const double DBL_EPSILON  =   2.2204460492503131e-016; /* smallest such that 1.0+DBL_EPSILON != 1.0 */` (note that I multiplied the value by 10 in the code I posted, because that's what the `IsZero()` implementation did). The question now is: Why did they multiply it by 10? I don't know the answer to that...

Comment: Yes ! I saw it through your link. But if double precision on 64bits is around e308, why limited it (on 64bits) at around E-15. This would be possible to use different constant "DBL_EPSILON" depending on the environment..